# Is a Bard/Duskblade or Bard/Monk multi-class feasible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, multi-classing, bard

I am using 3.0/3.5-style D&D. Free to delve into any other D&D books outside of 5.0 (DM dislikes 5.0).

I plan on playing an Aasimar, or a wood or water elf. We are starting at level 5.

I want to be able to fight in melee when needed, but like to be the underdog in the group who gets to show off here and there. I tend to create characters because I like them, not for power (e.g. I'll waste a spell slot just so I can have a certain eye and hair color).

My DM doesn't apply XP penalties for multiclassing. He would allow me to exchange longsword for rapier (Bard/Duskblade), but I would have to play a Chaotic Monk & take Monastic Training feat for the Bard/Monk build – which I am fine with.

**Is a Bard/Duskblade or Bard/Monk multi-class feasible?**

I want to know whether these builds are possible, and if so, whether they are a waste of time (i.e. will make no contribution to the team).

The 3 other party members are:

1. Dwarf - Paladin/Barbarian
2. Darkling - Shadow Caster/Beguiler
3. Unseelie - Ranger/Rogue

Comment: There really isn't any way for us to use non-3.x books for a 3.x character—the rules of different editions are just far too different for us to know how content in newer or older books would work in your game.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed the races you were looking at: where did you see a water elf? Did you mean aquatic elf? I can’t find a water elf.

Comment: A reminder to close voters that [very general char-op questions are explicitly endorsed and on-topic here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/4563). We have hundreds of questions just like this one that can get into a discussion of what needs to be considered for a particular combination. This question requires no more focus, no more details.

Answer (score 7):

### Duskblade/Bard: awkward

Duskblade, as a class, really wants to just be a duskblade. The quintessential duskblade feature—arcane channeling full-attack—requires duskblade 13th. Plus a duskblade wants full BAB and full spellcasting, which is hard to find (the one major option, abjurant champion from *Complete Mage*, is very easy for a duskblade to enter and can make a decent alternative to duskblade levels after 13th). It’s not impossible to multiclass duskblade, but there’s a lot of sacrifice and mostly you’d usually be better off ditching duskblade or ditching the other thing. And as a multiclass option, bard dips are usually all about Charisma, which a duskblade doesn’t use much.

Also, duskblades can use rapiers fine, no special steps necessary. Nothing about the class is specific to a longsword. The longsword is usually the superior weapon, but that’s minor.

### Monk/Bard: far more synergy

Monk is a far weaker class than duskblade in general, particularly if you compare a 20th-level duskblade to a 20th-level monk, but it is more multiclass friendly. Monk is a very front-loaded class, where almost all of its best features (unarmed strike, unarmored AC, evasion, bonus feats) are gained in the first two levels. Moreover, as a core class, monk has a ton more support, which can make it much more flexible and able to synergize with a variety of other classes.

For instance, Ascetic Mage (*Complete Adventurer*) could be taken by a 4th-level bard/1st-level monk to change the unarmored AC bonus from Wisdom to Charisma. That’s pretty nice for one level and one feat, and you’re free to continue improving bard from there, knowing you have pretty much all the best stuff from monk.

To play up your melee skills, Snowflake Wardance (*Frostburn*) gives you a bardic music option that adds your Charisma bonus to your attack rolls—you don’t need monk for that, but if you’re already adding Charisma to attack rolls, adding it to AC too looks that much better.

A second level of monk could be ok, if you can get a feat you want as bonus, and snag evasion or invisible fist (*Exemplars of Evil*) in the process. More levels of monk are not worthwhile: bard music and magic offer far better growth potential than anything left in the monk class.

### Also consider: Monk/Paladin/Bard

Along the same lines, divine grace (paladin 2nd) is one of the strongest class features in the game. A bard/monk/paladin with Ascetic Mage and Snowflake Wardance adds Charisma to attack, AC, and all saving throws—which is awesome. And that’s just three levels away from bard, so your music and spellcasting is nearly as good as a single-classed bard. This is a fairly typical “Charisma to everything” build, and it can be quite effective.

### About monk (and paladin) multiclassing

There is no need to take Monastic Training for what you want to do. The only thing it does is let you go back to monk after leaving it—but you want just one or two monk levels, so there’s nothing to go back for.

If, instead, you are saying that your DM has added a houserule saying you need Monastic Training to combine monk and bard at all, that’s pretty terrible, and comes close to making it just not worth it. A *+1 chain shirt* adds +5 to your AC; your Charisma bonus might be better (and applies against touch attacks), but probably not a **lot** better, so a level and two feats is a lot more dubious for the benefit.

The same is true of the similar Knight Training for paladin, if you go that route. Just take the 2 paladin levels in a row to get divine grace, and you’ll never need to return to paladin so you won’t need the feat. But if your DM houserules that you do need a feat... well honestly, divine grace is still worth it, but still, that is a houserule. For alignment concerns, note the [variants](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#paladinVariantsFreedomSlaughterAndTyranny) for other alignments: a paladin of liberty is just fine for our purposes.

Speaking of alignment, chaos monk is fine. Flailing strike is technically superior to flurry of blows on average, so maybe even worthwhile. But remember that neither ex-bards nor ex-monks actually lose anything: they can’t take more class levels, but they keep everything from the levels they have. So you can easily be a bard/ex-monk or ex-bard/monk. Since you want to continue with bard powers after monk, ex-monk/bard makes more sense. This does have the drawback that you can’t have bard as your 1st-level class—that costs you 8 skill points (it gains you 2 hp, but 8 skill points is worth a lot more than 2 hp). So chaos monk a way to have your cake and eat it too, so you can do your monk levels after bard 1st.

### Race

Your DM isn’t enforcing multiclass penalties (almost no one does, and absolutely no one should), but even if they were, none of these suggestions would have a problem with them so long as bard is a favored class. Human—particularly silverbrow human from *Dragon Magic*—is recommended anyway just because bonus feats are so good, so having bard as a favored class is not a problem.

But since you are interested in aasimar, wood elf, or water elf, the other alternative if you needed to avoid multiclass penalties is to use prestige classes rather than bard itself to advance the things you care about from bard: abjurant champion or unseen seer for greater martial capacity, or lyric thaumaturge for magic and music (all three from *Complete Mage*). Even though your DM is ignoring multiclass penalties, you may want to use these prestige classes anyway. Sublime chord (*Complete Arcane*) is also worthy of consideration.

As for the races you’re looking at, the LA +1 on aasimar is crippling: don’t do it. On the other hand, *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* describes variant, “lesser” aasimar that are LA +0—and also about the best race you could have, with the +2 Cha they get. So maybe ask your DM about that. On the other hand, lesser aasimar are pretty blatantly overpowered so that might not work out.

As for the elves, neither really does anything for you. No reason you can’t use them, but you might want to consider star elf (*Unapproachable East*) for +2 Cha. It also has −2 Con, which sucks, but a wood elf has the same **without** +2 Cha. Hellbred (*Fiendish Codex II*) and spellscales (*Races of the Dragon*) have the same +2 Cha/−2 Con, and maybe more interesting other things than star elves. There’s also the magic-blooded **template** from *Dragon* vol. 306 with the same +2 Cha/−2 Con, that can be added to any race—including one of the +2/−2 races for +4/−4. I don’t know if −4 Con is worth it—that is a lot of hp you’re losing—but +4 Cha at least makes it worth thinking about.

I still vote silverbrow human though. Maybe with magic-blooded.

Comment: I was skeptical of recommending monk over “literally anything else”, but you make some good points.

Comment: @fectin I mean, there are definitely a (very) few weaker classes. Ninja, soulborn, soulknife, truenamer...